# Optimization problem in warehouse

Tags: optimization

I need to optimize number of workers in my Warehouse. Suppose, there are three positions in the warehouse - A, B and C. Every person can work in all positions. Each day, some amount of goods arrives. Each piece of goods goes to position A, then B and finally C. I need to maximize the number of goods at position C at the end of the day by shifting my workers through the positions.

Mathematically speaking:

$A + B + C = 40$ ... Total number of workers is 40

$A \leq 10$ ... capacity of position A is 10

$B \leq 25$ ... capacity of position B is 25

$C \leq 15$ ... capacity of position C is 15

Let $G$ be the total amount of goods that arrives each morning. Workers have different productivity based on their position:

$G_{A} = min\{62 \cdot A; G\}
$ ... in other words, one worker in position A can process 62 pieces of goods, but obviously he cannot process more than is the total number of goods that arrives at the beginning of the day.

$G_{B} = min\{52 \cdot B - 1.1 \cdot B^{2}; G_{A}\}$ ... productivity of the worker B is concave. Same as above, total number of goods processed in B cannot be greater than number of goods from A, because A is an input for B.

Finally:

$G_{C} = min\{53 \cdot C - 0.9 \cdot C^{2}; G_{B}\}$... interpretation same as in B.

Do you have any idea, how to solve this type of problems, please? I was thinking about some linear programming, but the problem is that $G_{B}$ and $G_{C}$ is quadratic.. If you have any suggestions or link to similar problems, please share.

Comment: The definition of $G_A$ uses $G_A$, which seems to make a circular definition. The same applies for $G_B, G_C$. Can you define them without using themselves?

Comment: Maybe $G_A = \min\{62A, G\}$?

Comment: @KotaMori yes, thanks for your comment, I have edited my question.

Comment: The way you describe is more like the optimization of line balancing on the production floor. This means that we want to optimize from workstation 1 to ..n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this for this type of problem in general, but for this specific problem, the search space is so small that an exhaustive search is trivial.

First, notice that $\text{max}(G_B)=614$ at $B=23$. Start by enumerating all 45 possible arrangements of $\{A\leq10,B\leq23,C\leq15\}$ that satisfy $A+B+C=40$. Then determine the value of $G_C$ of each arrangement for some value $G\geq614$ (or $G\geq592$, which is the maximum value of $G_C$ at $C=15$), and select the arrangement with the largest value for $G_C$.

In R:

```
W <- expand.grid(list(A = 1:10, C = 1:15))
W$B <- 40 - rowSums(W)
W <- W[W$B <= 23,][c(1, 3, 2)]

GC <- with(
  W,
  pmin(floor(53*C - 0.9*C^2), pmin(floor(52*B - 1.1*B^2), pmin(62*A, 614)))
)
idx <- which.max(GC)
c(GC = GC[idx], W[idx,])
#> $GC
#> [1] 558
#> 
#> $A
#> [1] 9
#> 
#> $B
#> [1] 17
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 14
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why did you choose B = 23? Do you mean B = 25 which is the maximum capacity for position B?

Comment: As I mentioned, $G_B$ is maximized at $B=23$, so setting $B=24$ or $B=25$ will not increase $G_C$, and there's no reason to check those cases.

Comment: Thanks for clarification